# socket.id of disconnecting client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to get the `socket.id` of the client that has disconnected? The following code gives me `undefined` for `socket.id`

**Node.js Code**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function() {
    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        console.log(socket.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The callback function that `io.sockets.on` takes as its second argument is supposed to take one argument: the socket. Yours doesn't, so the socket on the second line's `socket.on` is undefined.

And the callback for `socket.on` isn't given any arguments, so the `socket` in that function is also undefined.

The code should work if you move the socket parameter from the second function declaration to the first:

```js
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id);
    });
});
```